# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Types inference failed in the call to 'Group Join'

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

```
var val1 =
                (from main in
                     (from irac in objIRAC
                      join iip in objIIP on irac.InvoiceItemID equals iip.InvoiceItemID
                      join oritc in
                          (from ritc in objRITC
                           join iips in objIIP on ritc.InvoiceItemPremiumID equals iips.InvoiceItemPremiumID
                           where ritc.ReconID == ReconId 
                                 && ritc.BookOfBusinessInvoiceItemPremiumID == BookOfBusinessInvoiceItemPremiumID 
                                 && ritc.InvoiceID == InvoiceId 
                           group new { ritc, iips } by new { ritc.ReconID, iips.InvoiceItemID }
                               into ritcs
                               select new
                               {
                                   ritcs.Key.ReconID,
                                   ritcs.Key.InvoiceItemID
                               }) on ReconId equals oritc.ReconID into oritcs // ReconId
                      from oritc in oritcs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where iip.InvoiceItemPremiumID == BookOfBusinessInvoiceItemPremiumID 
                      select new
                      {
                          oritc.InvoiceItemID,
                          irac.CommissionOnTypeID,
                          irac.BOBFamilyID,
                          irac.RateTypeID,
                          irac.Rate,
                          irac.CommissionAdjustmentFlag
                      })
                 join sub in objIRAC // Here getting the error
                 on new { main.InvoiceItemID, main.CommissionOnTypeID, main.BOBFamilyID, main.RateTypeID, main.Rate, main.CommissionAdjustmentFlag }
                 equals new { sub.InvoiceItemID, sub.CommissionOnTypeID, sub.BOBFamilyID, sub.RateTypeID, sub.Rate, sub.CommissionAdjustmentFlag }
                 into subs
                 from osub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { osub.InvoiceItemID });
```

Comment: Please format your question more clearly, and try to reduce the code until it's simple but still demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the types of

> main.InvoiceItemID, main.CommissionOnTypeID, main.BOBFamilyID, main.RateTypeID, main.Rate, main.CommissionAdjustmentFlag

and

> sub.InvoiceItemID, sub.CommissionOnTypeID, sub.BOBFamilyID, sub.RateTypeID, sub.Rate, sub.CommissionAdjustmentFlag

They should match exactly. That is: if one property is a `Nullable<int>` and the corresponding property is `int` it does not match. Since all properties but `InvoiceItemID` are from the same entity InvoiceItemID is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are one of your foreign key references are nullable, you'll need to do an explicit cast in order for the join (presuming inner join) to work.

```
var result =
  from a in context.T1
  join b in context.T2
    on new { s.Field1, s.Field2 }
    equals new { 
      Field1 = (int)b.T3.Field1 /* Join via sub-table, explicit conversion from int? to int  */
      ,Field2 = (int)b.Field2 /* explicit conversion from int? to int  */
    }
  where 
    b.T3.Field1 != null /* Specify no nulls allowed for inner-join fields */
    && b.Field2 != null
    && b.Field3 == InputVar1 /* Input Search Variables */
    && b.Field4 == InputVar2
  select a;
```

The above example was renamed from an actual query I am using.